# Why Wolfram gives inconsistent result for: $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{x-x^2}-e^{-x-x^2}}{x}~dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals, wolfram-alpha

Why Wolfram gives inconsistent result for :

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{x-x^2}-e^{-x-x^2}}{x}~dx$$

As shown in the picture below, the analytical integration gives $-i\pi$, but numerical integration gives $1.93193$. The result must be a real number, but why Wolfram gives a complex result for the analytical integration?

What I suspect is Wolfram might treat this integral as Frullani integral, where $f(x)=e^{x-x^2}$, and $f(-x)=e^{-x-x^2}$. We get


$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{x-x^2}-e^{-x-x^2}}{x}~dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{x}~dx=(f(\infty)-f(0))\ln\left(\frac1{-1}\right)=-i\pi$$
But this is WRONG!


[image]

Comment: As a general rule, it is hard to guess why Wolfram's algorithm would give us a strange/wrong result. If Wolfram showed work, it might be possible to figure it out, but your guess seems one reasonable possibility

Comment: @MathFail: maybe better to post this on the Mathematica Stack Exchange at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions.

Comment: When you use the Frullani integral, $a,b$ should have the same sign.

Comment: Yes, I know they need to be the same sign, but otherwise I can't explain why Wolfram gives complex result. @xpaul

Comment: For a brief moment, you may be able to see (possibly depending on whether one is signed in?) the correct result before $-i\pi$ replaces it in [W|A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28e%5E%28x-x%5E2%29-e%5E%28-x-x%5E2%29%29%2Fx+from+0+to+infinity). Consider submitting feedback to let the developers know.

Comment: This is not the answer the OP question, but it is interesting to note that the initial integral is
$$I(t=1)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sinh (tx)}xe^{-x^2}dx\,\bigg|_{t=1}$$
$$I'_t(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\cosh (xt)e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt\pi e^{\frac{t^2}4}\Rightarrow I(1)=\sqrt\pi\int_0^1e^{\frac{t^2}4}dt=1.93193...$$

Comment: Right, for about 1 sec, it first shows the correct result, which is real. and after 1 sec, it automatically changes back to the complex result which is wrong. Maybe we need to take a video on this moment. @user170231

Comment: I've had something similar happen to me before. I remember trying to parameterize some complicated vector over some shape and I typed my work into WA just in case I didn't make a sign error somewhere. Strangely, WA showed me the approximate form I got for half a second, then changed its mind and came up with a completely different answer.

Answer (score 5):

*Just a few elements (using Mathematica 13.1.0.0)*

- First case

$$I_1=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{a x-x^2}-e^{-a x-x^2}}{x}\,dx=\log (a)-\log (-a)=-i\,\pi$$

- Second case

$$I_2=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{a x-b x^2}-e^{-a x-c x^2}}{x}\,dx=$$
$$\frac{1}{4} a^2 \left(\frac{\,
   _2F_2\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{a^2}{4
   b}\right)}{b}-\frac{\,
   _2F_2\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{a^2}{4
   c}\right)}{c}\right)+$$ $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\pi 
   \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{a}{2
   \sqrt{b}}\right)+\text{erfi}\left(\frac{a}{2
   \sqrt{c}}\right)\right)-\log (b)+\log (c)\right)$$ If $c=b$, this reduces to
$$I_2=\pi \, \text{erfi}\left(\frac{a}{2 \sqrt{b}}\right)$$

- Third case
  $$I_3=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{a x-b x^2}-e^{-a x-b x^2}}{x}\,dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{2 \sinh (a x)}{x} e^{-b x^2}\,dx$$ $$I_3=\pi \, \text{erfi}\left(\frac{a}{2 \sqrt{b}}\right)$$

Comment: Sir, just a one question can't we rewrite given integral as $$ \int_0^\infty \left( \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{x} \right) e^{-x^2} dx = 2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)!} \int_0^\infty x^{2n} e^{-x^2} dx $$ I calculated and realized that it is giving wrong answer but why?

Comment: @LuckyChouhan. It gives the right answer since $$ 2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)!} \int_0^\infty x^{2n} e^{-x^2}\, dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(2 n+1)!}=\pi\,  \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Yeah, actually while evaluating the integral $$ \int_0^\infty x^{2n} e^{-x^2}dx $$ when I substitute $x^2 \to x $ I mistakenly wrote $x^n$ as $x^{1/2}$ so I was getting answer as $2 \sqrt{\pi} \sinh(1)$. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

**Feynman’s trick**

Consider the parametrised integral by $a$,
$$
I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{a x-x^2}-e^{-a x-x^2}}{x} d x
$$
where $I(0)=0.$
$$
\begin{aligned}
I’(a)=&\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\frac{a^2}{4}} d x-\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\frac{a^2}{4}} d x \\
= & e^{\frac{a^2}{a}}\left[\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2} d x-\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2} d x\right] \\
= & \frac{e^{\frac{a^2}{4}}}{2} \sqrt{\pi}\left[\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)+1+\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\right] \\
= & \sqrt{\pi} e^{\frac{a^2}{4}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrating from $a=0$ to $1$ yields
$$
I(1)=\sqrt{\pi} \int_0^1 e^{\frac{a^2}{4}} d a
$$
Hence we can conclude that
$$
\boxed{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{x-x^2}-e^{-x-x^2}}{x} d x=\sqrt{\pi}\left[\sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]=\pi\operatorname{erfi}\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)\approx {1.93193}\;}
$$
which doesn’t agree with WA.